# How do i programmatically change a field's 'Widget' property under 'Manage Form Display' & a fields 'Format' property under Manage Display?

Tags: 8, users, entities

How do i programmatically change a field's 'Widget' property under 'Manage Form Display' & a fields 'Format' property under Manage Display?

Manage Form Display:

I'd want to programmatically change the Birthdate field's 'widget' property to 'Textfield' to make it visible on forms when my module is installed/enabled.

[image]

Manage Display:

I'd want to programmatically change the Birthdate field's 'format' property to 'Plain Text' to make it visible on forms when my module is installed/enabled.

[image]

Comment: You already asked this yesterday? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224686/8-how-do-i-programmatically-enable-a-user-field-under-manage-form-display-and

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't know that I I now have powers to close issues as duplicate immediately due to the gold badge, this must be new..